# Laravel 5.2 artisan commands not working

Tags: laravel-5

i just installed a fresh laravel 5.2. But anytime i try to run an artisan command i get this error `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()`

Answer (score 0):

bindshared() is a deprecated method since Laravel 5.1
Check the file that triggers the error using the -vvv flag on the artisan command:

```
php artisan {command} -vvv
```

This will display a complete stack trace and you'll be able to understand what's happening. After this, change the *bindShared()* call to *singleton()* in the file that triggers the error and **probably** everything will run properly. Consider the possibility that the error is triggered by an outdated additional package installed via composer.

Comment: the same error comes up how can i find the bindShared and change it?

Comment: i run a fresh laravel installation and its working now

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the composer and from `"laravel/framework": "5.1.*"` you should edit that to `"laravel/framework": "5.2.*"`.

That will solve the issue.

`bindshared()` is now deprecated. The laravel  core is changed.